# Style google sign in button?

Tags: android

In google's guidelines it's recommended to make a sign out button and style it.

I've implemented the sign out button, but i'm having difficulty styling it, setting the icon, and "properness" that the guideline is asking for.

Does anyone have any examples I can use as an example for this?

How can i set their logo and center the text properly?

[Google button guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can style google icons according to guidelines. Following code can be used for button using selectors :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/google_btn_bg">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/google_icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Sign Out"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code for its background for this button i.e. **google_btn_bg**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#DF4A32"></solid>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DF4A32"
        />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```